# Transforms not working

Tags: assets, image-transforms

Having issues getting Craft to use a transform I set in the CP: `squarePhoto`. I keep getting a template error, even though that transform exist.

> Variable "squarePhoto" does not exist

The template code in question is:

```
{% for asset in block.photoImages %}
    <img src="{{ asset.getUrl(squarePhoto) }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}">
{% endfor %}
```

After digging through other threads, I saw that Craft adds a subfolder to the directory with the transform name–this has not been generated. What am I missing?

I've also added the config var `'generateTransformsBeforePageLoad' => true,` to my general.php to see if that made a difference.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's a very subtle difference, but what you have added there is a variable, when what you are looking for is a string.

```
<img src="{{ asset.getUrl('squarePhoto') }}" alt="{{ asset.title }}">
```

Notice the difference?

Your current way would be correct if you had set a variable somewhere with the name of squarePhoto, like so:

```
{% set squarePhoto = 'transformName' %}
```

Check out the [Twig Primer](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/twig-primer) in the Craft docs.

Comment: Very subtle indeed! Thanks for the description to, it helps to understand the differences